# Java Quicksort algorithm Stack Overflow with Big array sizes

Tags: java, data-structures, stack-overflow, quicksort

I'm working on implementing a Quicksort algorithm which I've got to work fine with array sizes up to 100,000. Once I try to sort with a size of 1,000,000 I get a stack overflow error (which is happening to my best understanding due to the recursive functionality of my algorithm).
I know this question has been asked on here before, but none of those answers helped me at all. I've looked through my code extensively, and even modeled it off a Java textbook just to double check, still no fix.
I've been reading on here for at least an hour trying to solve this, and I read that the call stack could hold up to 8MB or so depending on the system. I'm wondering if either:

- My algorithm is wrong
- 1,000,000 elements is too large to use for a quicksort (with this compiler).

**EDIT: To anyone interested: I discovered that increasing my random interval from 1-9 to 1-n (n being the size of the sequence being sorted, ex: 1-1000000), my quicksort ran extremely faster, and of course didn't have any overflow problems.**

I'm going to submit my code now, with the driver, and hopefully someone can quickly show me where I went wrong.

```
public class QuickSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //JUST TO TEST THAT IT WORKS
    int[]A = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}; //worst case

    quickSort(A, 0, A.length-1);

    //print the array
    for (int a :A)
        System.out.print(a+" ");
    System.out.println();

}

/**
 * Quicksort algorithm, O(n log n) best and average case, O(n^2) worst case
 * @param S sequence to sort
 * @param a the lower bound of sequence
 * @param b upper bound of sequence
 */
public static void quickSort(int[]S, int a, int b) {
    if (a >= b)
        return;
    int p = S[b]; //setting pivot to the last element in sequence
    int l = a;
    int r = b - 1;
    int temp;

    while (l <= r) { //once left and right have crossed this will end while
        while (l<= r && S[l] <= p) {
            l++; //move in from left side until found an element greater than the pivot
        }
        while (l <= r && S[r] >= p) {
            r--; //move in from right side until element found less than the pivot
        }
        if (l <= r) {
            //swap S[l] and S[r] //swap the left and right elements if they haven't crossed
            temp = S[l];
            S[l] = S[r];
            S[r] = temp;
            l++;
            r--;
        }
    }
    //left and right have crossed here
    //swap S[l] and S[b] //put the pivot back to the new partition spot
    temp = S[l];
    S[l] = S[b];
    S[b] = temp;
    quickSort(S, a, l-1); //call quicksort on our new sublists partitioned around our pivot
    quickSort(S, l+1, b);
    //recursive calls

}
```

}

**The Driver:**

```
import java.util.Random;
```

public class SortingCompare {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.printf("Sorting Run Times:\n");
    System.out.printf("Array Size   Insertion Sort%5s%s\n", " ","Quick sort");

        int A[] = new int[100000];
        int n = 100000;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            A[i] = rand.nextInt(9) + 1; //1-9
        }
        //array is filled with random integers

        //long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //InsertionSortInPlace.insertionSort(A);
        //long insertionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //    A[i] = rand.nextInt(9) + 1; //1-9
        //}

        long startQuickSort = System.currentTimeMillis();
        QuickSort.quickSort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
        long quickTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startQuickSort;

        System.out.printf("%-5d%10dms%15s%dms\n", n, insertionTime, " ", quickTime);

}
```

}

Comment: I would highly recommend that you use insertionsort for partitions smaller than 1000 Elements. That is how the quicksort algorythm is used in Java Collection for example.

Comment: You recurse all the way down to single item partitions.  That gives very deep stacks.

Comment: @Christian 1000 is far too high. It was traditionally 15 or 16 following Knuth and Sedgewick. The threshold below which the collections don't sort is 47.

Comment: Interesting, I found insertion sort way faster until about 15 elements or so as well.

Comment: I’m going to look up the Canonical version. Thanks!

Comment: To anyone interested: I discovered that increasing my random interval from 1-9 to 1-n (n being the size of the sequence being sorted, ex: 1-1000000), my quicksort ran extremely faster, and of course didn't have any overflow problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort the smaller of the two partitions first, to minimize stack usage, and use an insertion sort for partitions less than say 16 elements.

You also need to look up the Quicksort algorithm. You don't need two tests in each inner loop: they completely destroy the point of the algorithm; and the details of your implementation vary from the canonical version by Sedgewick.

Comment: @dave99collins You're talking to the wrong person. I didn't suggest `Arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quicksort from Java that is optimized both for performance and memory usage, so in your code replace:

```
quickSort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
```

with:

```
Arrays.sort(A);
```

In order to run the modified code you need the following import:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```